# jQuery dynamic changing image header

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam trying to write a simple jQuery function to change the image header of my webpage.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="slider"> 
<ul>
<li> <img src="img/slide21.png" alt=""> </li>
<li> <img src="img/slide31.png" alt=""> </li>
```

I just want to fade in the next image every 5 seconds and fade out the old.
The position of the image should not change and all images are the same size.

My js code looks like this:

```
function menu (obj) {
if (!obj.length) {
  return;
}
  $(obj).find("li").hide();
  $(obj).find("li").next().fadeIn(2400);
}
 $(document).ready(function () {
   menu(".slider");
 });
}
```

This code is really not what I want but currently I have no idea how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

since you're using jQuery already, take a look at the cycle plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Answer (score 0):

you can use settimeout:

```
function change_image(obj) {
    $(obj).find("li").fadeOut();
    $(obj).find("li").next().fadeIn();
}

var menu_obj;
function menu(obj) {
   ...
   menu_obj = obj
   setTimeout("change_image(menu_obj);", 5000);

}
```

Fadeout and fadein have a default of 500 I think, which is half a second for the actual fade animation.

You could also probably do something like:

```
$(obj).find("li:first-child").delay(5000).fadeOut().next().find("li").fadeIn();
```

Where the delay function delays jQuery's animation queue.

However, your selector find("li") will find all of the LI elements and fade them all out then find their siblings and attempt to fade them in, so you'll need something like li:first-child or li:nth-child(x) and keep a running count. The problem with nth-child is that I'm not sure that the CSS is supported in IE... but the jQuery selector will still work I believe.

Anyway, you'll have to play with it, maybe keep a global variable around that keeps track of the current image and call next() on that (being careful to put in a check for the end of the list which requires you to start over at first-child). You could use the length of the number of LIs to ensure this, or keep a pointer to the obj > li:last-child element and test for it.

OR, just go ahead and use an image-cycle plugin as suggested.

Personally when I do cycling images I just create a div that is wide enough to hold all the images with a div that is wide enough to hold just ONE image as its container, then set it to clip any overflow, and have a jquery function that changes the position or margin by a factor of N * image_width every M seconds where N is the number of images.

Here's an example of one done differently:

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3881826/JavaScript-Tutorial-Adding-Rotating-Images-to-Your-Web-Site.htm

It might at least give you ideas about `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

A few months ago I built a simple image transition script which has worked quite well.  Rather than just swapping the image, my script first sets the background of the containing div to be the first image.  This way, when the first image gets hidden there is no flickering while the second image fades in.  You can view the transition at [AdairHomes.com](http://adairhomes.com), it is the large image rotation.

## HTML Wrapper

```
  <div id="galleryContent" style="background:url(images/simple-banner-image-bath.jpg) top left;">
    <img id="bannerImage" src="<!--Place the first image source here-->" alt="<!--Place your first ALT tag here-->" width="960" height="562" />
  </div>
```

## jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var banners = new Array();
    // Array of images which you want to cycle
    banners = [{"Source":"images/simple-banner-image-construction2.jpg","Alt":"Construction - Framing"},
               {"Source":"images/simple-banner-image-bath.jpg","Alt":"Signature Custom Bathroom"},
               {"Source":"images/simple-banner-image-2659.jpg","Alt":"Model Signature 2659"},
               {"Source":"images/simple-banner-image-kitchen.jpg","Alt":"Signature Custom Kitchen"},
               {"Source":"images/simple-banner-image-2432.jpg","Alt":"Model Signature 2432"},
               {"Source":"images/simple-banner-image-1405.jpg","Alt":"Model Signature 1405"},
               {"Source":"images/simple-banner-image-2830.jpg","Alt":"Model Signature 2830"}];

    var count = banners.length - 1; // subtracting 1 accounts for the array starting at [0]
    var counting = 0;
    going = setInterval(function(){

      $("#bannerImage").fadeOut(200,function(){
        $(this).attr({'src':banners[counting]['Source'],'alt':banners[counting]['Alt']}).fadeIn(200);
      });

      // Select Next Picture
      if(counting != count){counting++;}else{counting = 0;}

      // Set new background image
      $("#galleryContent").css({'background':'url('+banners[counting]['Source']+') top left'});
    },6000);

    var loadCount = 1;

    // Preload images after the first image is displayed
    slowLoad = setInterval(function(){
      if(loadCount < banners.length){
        $("body").append('<img src="'+banners[loadCount]['Source']+'" style="display:none;" />');
        loadCount++;
      }else{
        clearInterval(slowLoad);
      }
    },500);    

</script>
```

You'll notice that I have opted to keep all of the images that I am rotating in an array.  This is because I manage all of my included images with PHP.

With this code, you will essentially only need to style the `#galleryContent` div to look the way you want it to look and add all of your images with their alt tags to the banners array.  You will also need to place whichever header you want to show up first, into the `#bannerImage`.

Let me know if you need any more code or assistance.  I think you can get a pretty good feel of it from my link above.